# PHP Autoloading (Efficiently)

Tags: php, autoload

I have a problem with autoloading classes that have not been named appropriately. While our developers always use the Java-style file-name-same-as-class approach so autoloading functions are trivial, we suddenly got a brick to the liver when [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) came along.

For the record, their naming system goes like this:

- **Hybrid_Auth** exists in *Hybrid/Auth.php*
- **Hybrid_Provider_Adapter** exists in *Hybrid/Provider_Adapter.php*
- **Hybrid_Providers_Facebook** exists in *Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php*
- **OAuthRequest** (along with several others) exist in *Hybrid/thirdparts/OAuth/OAuth.php*

And this is what it did to our lovely little, harmonious autoloader:

#### Original

```
function autoload($class)
{
    $search = array('classes',
                    'utils',
                    'config');

    foreach($search as $folder)
    {
            $file = ROOT_DIR.'/'.$folder.'/'.$class.'.php';

            if(file_exists($file)) 
            {
                    require_once $file;
            }
    }
}
```

#### After HybridAuth

```
function autoload($class)
{
    // FIXME: This is horrid.

    $search = array('classes',
                    'utils',
                    'config',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/LinkedIn',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth',
                    'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OpenID');

    // Stupid Hybrid Auth not using good file naming schemes
    if (strstr($class, 'OAuth')) require_once ROOT_DIR.'/'.'utils/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php';
    $class = str_replace('Hybrid_', '', $class);
    $class = str_replace('Providers_', '', $class);

    foreach($search as $folder)
    {
            $file = ROOT_DIR.'/'.$folder.'/'.$class.'.php';

            if(file_exists($file)) 
            {
                    require_once $file;
            }
    }
}
```

It's mullered it! What can I try to make something neater again without modifying HybridAuth's source?

Comment: You can statically invoke require_once on all the HybridAuth files so that you don't pollute your autoloader, I think it's the best thing to do...

Comment: And you should definitely use a PSR-0 autoloader like Symfony's one: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/class_loader.html (it won't solve HybridAuth's problem, but sill...)

Comment: @Nanocom Will statically loading them all be effective if I have 31 classes to load in?

Comment: 31 classes is not that much.

Comment: I really don't understand their naming convention, they nearly follow PSR-0 except for some classes